# Which RBAC role is required to approve a Private Endpoint Connection (on an Event Hub namespace)?

Tags: azure, azure-rbac, azure-private-link

What is the minimum Azure RBAC (built-in) role required to approve a Pending Private Endpoint Connection (on an Event Hub namespace)? So far we managed to do it with **Contributor** on the Event Hub Namespace but we are wondering if there is a role which grants less permissions and still will work for this.

Comment: Clone default Azure Event Hubs Data Owner role and create a custom role for only approving private endpoint in Event Hub namespace: https://i.imgur.com/VGobGjB.png

Comment: @VenkatV so that means there isn't a built-in role which would achieve that (without granting Contributor etc)?

Comment: There is a built-in role to manage the Event Hub namespace. However, if you want to restrict permissions specifically for private endpoint approval, you can create a custom role : https://i.imgur.com/jHDgQeT.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the minimum Azure RBAC (built-in) role required to approve a Pending Private Endpoint Connection (on an Event Hub namespace)?

There is a built-in role called `Azure Event Hubs Data Owner` in the **Event Hub** namespace that is specifically designed for managing **Event Hub** resources. This role provides complete access to **Event Hubs** resources

Refer the this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#azure-event-hubs-data-owner) for more about the `Azure Event Hubs Data Owner` Role.

**Azure Event Hubs Data Owner**

[image]

In order to provide access specifically for approving private endpoints in the `Event Hub namespace`, you can create a **custom role** by cloning the `"Azure Event Hubs Data Owner"` role and removing all other actions, selecting only the **"Approve Private Endpoint Connection"** permission

[image]